# I would like to know how to stop form submission when the validation fails?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am new to php here's the my code.

when any of the field is empty i want to stop form submission...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else if (empty($_POST["website"]))
     {$website = "";}
   else if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
     {$comment = "";}
   else if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
     {$genderErr = "Gender is required";}

}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="welcome.php"> 
   <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website"> <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
   <br><br>
   <label>Gender:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print all the errors, so your code should be like below...

```
<?php session_start(); error_reporting(0);?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$_SESSION['name']= "Name is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$_SESSION['email'] = "Email is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["website"]))
     {$_SESSION['website'] = "Website is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
     {$_SESSION['comment'] = "comment is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
     {$_SESSION['gender'] = "Gender is required";}
}
if($_POST['name']!="" && $_POST['email']!="" && $_POST['website']!="" && 

$_POST['gender']!="")
{
    header("Location: welcome.php");
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action=""> 
   <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website"> <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['website'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
   <br><br>
   <label>Gender:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['gender'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['website']);
    unset($_SESSION['comment']);
    unset($_SESSION['gender']);
?>
```

If you want to access all the variables in Welcome page. just code like below

**home.php**

```
<?php session_start(); error_reporting(0);?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 


<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="welcome.php"> 
   <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website"> <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['website'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
   <br><br>
   <label>Gender:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['gender'];?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['website']);
    unset($_SESSION['comment']);
    unset($_SESSION['gender']);
?>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$_SESSION['name']= "Name is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$_SESSION['email'] = "Email is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["website"]))
     {$_SESSION['website'] = "Website is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
     {$_SESSION['comment'] = "comment is required";}
   if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
     {$_SESSION['gender'] = "Gender is required";}

}
if(empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["website"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]))
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: I would like to show the error in this page itself and prevent from navigating it to "welcome.php"???

Comment: yes, error will display on the page itself, try in this way. at the end don't forget to `unset` all session variables.

Comment: at the end means where exactly? cos im really new to php

Comment: i jus pasted ur whole code...
Still if i click submit button with all d fields empty the page is moving to welcome.php..

Comment: ya got it but u have removed welcome.php from form action
wen all the fields are valid den how to navigate to welcome.php??

Comment: now its not navigating for me
d page is just reloading i pasted the whole code...
and 1 more thing if i navigate using this method will i be able to access these variables in the next page??

Comment: no you can't able to access using `$_POST` method but if you want to access them, you need code this validations on welcome page.. when validation fire, you will redirect it to the previous page.

Comment: @Shashank yeah jQuery is good but it will not run when JavaScript is disable on client's browser.

Comment: @Shashank as Sumit says, client-side validation is great but if your users do not run Javascript you will potentially leave your PHP app open to errors and possible security issues. You should always validate and clean data server-side.

Comment: I feel @shashank is excessively lazy hoping people will just do their work for em...the answer to their inquiry is clearly laid out. This post was most helpful to my ends, thanks Sumit :)...fyi...this should probably be accepted as the answer.

Comment: this doesn't really stop the form from being submitted

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate your data before you submit,you should be using javascript more specifically jquery to validate the data client side itself,

Give the form an id like this

method="post" action="welcome.php" id="**form1**"

and ids to all your form elements

`$('#form1').submit(function() {
     your validation rules here

     if($('#email').val().length == 0)
       return false;
    else 
       return true;
});`

return false stops the submission.

If you are going to do front end and not just php you should really have a go at jquery will make your life easier

Comment: i don want to take the help of js or jquery
 i jus waned to kno whether its possible in php..

Comment: then add an else at the last and add your submission code there

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is client side, PHP is server side so until the submit button is not pressed to "Post data to server" and from there you use php to validate the form .. check fields do different operations like database inserts, calculations etc, you cannot send a response back to the client and tell him you here mate got this error i ain't going to work with this kind of data. Well, you could use ajax to live validate the form on server side. the best way to do is to validate client side and then before you use all that data that comes from the client who always lies because everybody lies you do another checking on server. Here is an [example.](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it with PHP for the PDO Database:

- It won't submit to your database until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

I added an If statement to the connection.

```
<?php
 // define variables and set to empty values
   $nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
   $name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Please add a name";
  } else {
      $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white 
      space allowed";} 
    }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please add an email";
  } else {
     $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
     // check if email is an email format
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      }
    }

 if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "Please add your city";
  } else {
    $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
    // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
  } else {
    $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
       // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
        $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
  } else {
    $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

    }
}

// Validate Form Data 
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }


if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
  {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      echo "Success! Form Submitted!";
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 




<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
  <div class="error">
    <p><span>* required field</span></p>
    <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
  </div>
    <label for="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="city">city:
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
       <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="comment">comment:
      <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this if you want to redirect it to another page so it won't send the form again to your PDO database if they refresh it.

- It won't submit to your database and will stay on the HOME.PHP page until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages while on HOME.PHP page.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

Added a "header("Location: welcome.php");" after "$conn->exec($sql);"

**HOME.PHP**

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Please add a name";
  } else {
    $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";} 
    }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please add an email";
  } else {
    $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
    // check if email is an email format
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "Please add your city";
  } else {
    $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
    // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
  } else {
    $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
       // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
        $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
  } else {
    $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

    }
}

// Validate Form Data 
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }


if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
  {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      header("Location: welcome.php");
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 




<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
  <div class="error">
    <p><span>* required field</span></p>
    <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
  </div>
    <label for="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="city">city:
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
    <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="comment">comment:
      <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WELCOME.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Success! Form Submitted!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to  do the validation in PHP, but stop submitting data to PHP. That isn't possible. If you'd like to validate in PHP, all the data will be submitted no matter what. You can use `exit()` to stop PHP executing if you need to. Otherwise, you'll need to validate the form client-side using JavaScript (something you can find plenty of information about here or through Google).

Answer (score 0):

I you need form doesn't get submitted if any of the field is empty why don't you try this..

```
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" required> <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
    <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email" required> <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website" required> <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment" required>
       <br><br>
       <label>Gender:</label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required>Female
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male
```

Comment: i don want to take the help pf html5
i kno other various ways to do this using js or jquery
i jus waned to kno whether its possible in php..

Answer (score 0):

you can do an array for Errors ,

```
$errors = []; // empty array 

if(isset($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['username'])) {
   $errors['userName'] = "The userName is empty";
}

// then check if no errors , insert it to your DB :
if(count($errors) <= 0) {
 // after filtering the username from XSS , insert it to DB.
}else {
 // If there are ERRORS , even if one error :
 foreach($errors as $error) {
 // you can print all your errors 
}
}

// or use then in onther place like this :
if(isset($errors['username'])) { 
  echo $erros['username'];
}
```

or you can use JavaScript xmlHttpRequest ,
READ about preventDefault function,

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the form with this function:

```
$("form").submit(function(a){
    a.preventDefault();
});
```